# Target Action to UIButton of nib not working in parentViewConteroller

Tags: swift

I am trying to add targetAction to my UIButton of my subView. 
Here is how I add UINib to my parentViewController.

```
let myView = UINib(nibName: "myNibName", bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! CarTypeCollectionCell
myView.setData(param, secondParam)
self.mainView.addSubview(myView)
myView.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickBtn(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And here is my onClickBtn function.

```
@objc func onClickBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
   print("this is clicked")
}
```

But the button action is not working. I set all of my button and view **isUserInteractionEnabled** to **true**. 
When I tried with UITapGesture to myNibView, its working pretty well. But not with in that button addTarget case. 
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: on #selector your action is called  onclickBtn(_:)  but your func has capital C. onClickBtn

Comment: Nah. that was just my typing error when i copy in that question.

Comment: I tried your code its working fine at my end

Comment: where are you writing the above code

Comment: In my ViewController which appear with present modally over current context setting. @ShivamGaur

Comment: @MinKhantLu check the self reference where is it pointing.

Comment: its pointing to my viewController which present via present modally @ShivamGaur

Comment: @MinKhantLu Try adding the withOwner parameter to be the YourViewController.self, eq -> let myView = UINib(nibName: "myNibName", bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: YourViewController.self, options: nil).first as! CarTypeCollectionCell

Comment: still not working. But When I add tapGesture to my whole CarTypeCollectionCell, tap gesture is working fine, @ShivamGaur

Comment: Just for check make onClickBtn Static and add selector that way, if it is still not going then there is issue with your button.